# Make points progress like Visual studio?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Iam a novice programmer who basically just started,im not sure what I should search for my issue,what I wanna do is making those points like Visual studio if someone already saw VS 2012-13 already installing , those points keep progressing and dissapearing ,hope some can help me out.

[image: ttp://i.stack.imgur.com/WlBqg.png]

Comment: cannot be done on WinForms ?

Comment: @user3832856: You can do anything in WinForms, if you're willing to write the rendering code yourself...

Comment: You could even use assembler. But I wrote the tool that I would use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with ascii and a label?
You can manage to wait for the process load and stuff so meanwhile you can show this:

```
label l1 = new label();
label.Location = new Point(X location, Y location) //Location despends on you
```

and then just add this in:

```
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
label l1 = new label();
label.Location = new Point(X location, Y location) //Location despends on you
_load();
}
```

Create a timmer method:

```
    private async void _load()
    {
        string[] n = { " ", "  ", "   ", "    ", "     ", "      ", "       ", "        ", "         ", "          " };
        while (true)
        {
            l1.Text = "• • • • •";
            await Task.Delay(500);
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                if (i < 4)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(50);
                    l1.Text = "• • • •" + n[i] + "•";
                }
                else if(i >4 && i< 7)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    l1.Text = "• • • •" + n[i] + "•";
                }
                else
                {
                    await Task.Delay(180);
                    l1.Text = "• • • •" + n[i] + "•";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You just have to use the head to guess how to make it look like the VS's one D:
Strings are funny :3

Comment: C# (.NET) System.String uses Unicode, not ASCII. So, a large number of potential characters are available, including the • you suggested (which isn't ASCII).

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.  Microsoft is violating their own [UI guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  (See #11 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)].

Instead, indicate progress using a standard [`ProgressBar` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  That's what it is for, and all [your users already recognize its meaning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The animation you indicate is most similar to [the Marquee style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the standard progress bar.

[image]